# Addition in dictionary of python

Tags: python

I am supposed to add to each value within the dictionary such that it increases by 1.

```
def increasee(d):
    for i in d.values():
        if i == { } :
            return d
        else:
            for k in d.keys():
                d[k] += 1
            return d
```

This accounts for when d.values are empty and when the the key just contains an integer but when there is a dictionary within a dictionary, like

```
increase({'a':{'b':{'c':16}}})
{'a':{'b':{'c':17}}}
```

should I be using nested loops? Or should I use recursive?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to handle an empty dictionary, because the `for k` loop is then not iterating.

To handle nested dictionaries, use recursion:

```
def increase(d):
    for key in d:
        if isinstance(d[key], dict):
            increase(d[key])
        else:
            d[key] += 1
    return d
```

This loops over the keys of the dictionary directly (no need to call `.keys()` here; the dictionary is itself iterable).

You are also altering the dictionaries *in-place*; there is no need to return anything here, really. I've retained an outer `return d` for you anyway, to return the outermost dictionary; return values of recursive calls are ignored.

Demo:

```
>>> def increase(d):
...     for key in d:
...         if isinstance(d[key], dict):
...             increase(d[key])
...         else:
...             d[key] += 1
...     return d
... 
>>> increase({'a':{'b':{'c':16}}})
{'a': {'b': {'c': 17}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the depth of your `dict`s, you should go for recursion:

```
def increase(d):
    for i in d.values():
        if i == {} :
            return d
        else:
            for k in d.keys():
                if type(d[k]) is dict:
                    increase(d[k])
                else:
                    d[k] += 1
            return d

print increase({'a':{'b':{'c':16}}})
```

Pleas note that this code is given as an example only. It will fail when one of the values is not a number. For example, this will raise an error:

```
increase({'a':{'b':{'c':'some text'}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is good for this case.

```
def dict_inc(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dict_inc(v)
        elif isinstance(v, int):
            d[k] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that makes a copy:

```
def increased(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return { k: increased(v) for k, v in d.iteritems() }
    else:
        return d + 1
```

```
>>> d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {}, 'd': 1}}}
>>> increased(d)
{'a': {'b': {'c': {}, 'd': 2}}}
>>> d
{'a': {'b': {'c': {}, 'd': 1}}}
```